# Unable to create javax script engine for javascript in Javafx application

Tags: javascript, javafx, build

I am using NetBeans 12.0. and windows 10 64 bit.My JDK is 15.0.2 and JavaFx SDK 16. When I try to build my javafx application it shows the following build error:

C:\Users\musta\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavafxTry\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1251: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\musta\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavafxTry\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1259: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript

BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

The Nashorn JavaScript Engine has been removed in Java 15:
https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372

Comment: Thank you. But how can I fix this? i mean what I should I do? I am a beginner in Java help me please. Give me some details. It would be very nice.

Comment: @MustafaIram There are several possibilities:
1. You could go back to Java 14 or older.
2. Replace the code that requires JavaScript.
3. Migrate to GraalVM: https://golb.hplar.ch/2020/04/java-javascript-engine.html

Answer (score 1):

The javascript engine used to be included in the JVM but it has been removed in [Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372).

As an alternative you can use [Groovy](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/groovy-ant-task.html) instead. Groovy looks similar to javascript. Your javascript should be easy to port to Groovy.

When you use the 'groovy-all jar', the script tag looks something like:

```xml
<taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpath="path/to/groovy-all-2.4.21.jar" />
<groovy>
    // your Groovy script
</groovy>
```

Comment: This isn't always going to help; The same error appears if trying to build pure-java applications, because it's coming from (what I presume are) Netbeans-generated build/configure files. I.e. users can encounter this even if they haven't touched a line of javascript. In which case the correct way of replacing/fixing Netbean's build files with Groovey is pretty unclear.