# JS Engine Creation Failed

Tags: javafx

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Aniket Kumbhar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyMediaPlayer1\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Aniket Kumbhar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyMediaPlayer1\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1251: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Aniket Kumbhar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyMediaPlayer1\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1259: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript
Got this error

Solution???

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611827/230513).