# javaFX in netbeans application

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-platform

**Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform.**
Please go to Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab,
enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime.
Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website.

Comment: Instructions on using JavaFX and NetBeans are in the getting started documentation at openjfx.io.  If you follow instructions from elsewhere it may be outdated and misleading.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NetBeans 14 - Failed to automatically set-up JavaFX Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73607287/netbeans-14-failed-to-automatically-set-up-javafx-platform)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Follows this Guide: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

**Solution 2:**

You could use this tool to generate a preconfigured working non modular Gradle JavaFX project the easy way (you need Java 17 installed):

Download link:

https://wedasoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/JavaFxProjectGenerator-1.2.1.jar

Website:

https://wedasoft.com/projects/javafx-project-generator/