How to setup Java Fx 22 in Netbeans 21, jdk 22?

According to the red colored texts,
I went to "Manage Platforms" and
clicked "Add Platforms". Then
I clicked "Java Standard Edition"  and then
clicked "javafx-sdk-22.0.1".
After that I can't click "Next" .
And I don't know how a Java FX tab will come.






What should I do to run Java FX (version 22) in "Apache Netbeans IDE 21" , JDK 22.0.1?

I don't use NetBeans, but instructions for setting up JavaFX in NetBeans are at openfjx.io.  Whether it works with the version of NetBeans you are using, I don't know.

With reference to @jewelsea's link: for a non-modular project, "Create a new global Library under Tools -> Libraries -> New Library." Alternatively, consider a modular with [tag:maven] project.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/73607287/2423906

Your screens are for setting the JDK, not for setting the JavaFX version. Instead, follow these steps:
Create JavaFX Project
File -> New Project  ->
Choose Project Window

Catefories -> Java with Maven
Projects   -> Simple JavaFX Maven Archetype
Button -> Next

Finding Feature Window
[V] JavaFX Implementation for Windows (amd64)

Button --> Download and Activate...

NetBeans IDE Installer
Welcome to the NetBeans IDE Plugin Installer
JavaFX Implementation for Windows (amd64)[17.12]

Button -> Next

License Agreement
[V] I accept the terms in all of the license Agreements.

Button -> Next

Installation completed successfully

Button -> Finish

popup Name and Location Window
Wait a moment.
Additional Creation Properties:

Key: javafx-version

Value: 13 <--- default value , change it to 22

Button -> Finish


Run Project
Menu -> Run -> Project (your project)
It will show Hello, JavaFX 22, running on Java 22.0.1.
Edit pom.xml
Projects -> Project Files -> pom.xml
change version to 22 (JDK version)
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

in this part is JavaFX version : 22
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

In Maven Project, change pom.xml config.

Copyedit to un-bury the lede; please revert if unwarranted.
